# Five one hundred rupee/s note/s

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which one is correct

- I have five one-hundred rupee note.
- I have five one-hundred rupee notes.
- I have five one-hundred rupees notes.

Answer (score 4):

You would write

> I have five one-hundred rupee notes.

The notes are plural, and "one-hundred rupee" modifies a single note.

Most publications numeralize numbers over ten, so you can also write

> I have five 100-rupee notes.

Comment: That last point is a good one; I've seen style guides that recommend a mixed approach for a situation like this. For example, those guides would recommend using _forty 50-rupee notes_, or _40 fifty-rupee notes_, but avoiding _forty fifty-rupee notes_, or _40 50-rupee notes_.

Answer (score 1):

Singular terms of measure are used in compound expressions of measure; five ten-ton weights, three six-gallon barrels, three five-foot-long poles; thus only your second example is correct.

> I have five one-hundred rupee notes.